# php-mcrypt (remi) error while upgrading from php 5.4 to 5.6 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, php, centos7, php56, php-mcrypt

I'm trying to upgrade php on CentOS 7 from 5.4 to 5.6.

When I run

```
 yum install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo
```

I get this dependency error. There were many others, so I removed them with `yum` and conflicts are gone. But `php-mcrypt` remains.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Installed: php-common-5.6.40-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.39-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
           Installed: php-common-5.6.40-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.39-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

If I try to remove `php-mcrypt`

```
yum remove php-mcrypt
```

I get this error.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
No Match for argument: php-encrypt
No Packages marked for removal
```

Only repos I have `centos`, `epel` and `remi`

I'm running `centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64`

I have 5.6, checked with `php -v` and `phpinfo();` but no mcrypt.

Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW, PHP 5.6 is end of life as well, http://php.net/supported-versions.php So you should consider 7.x.

Answer (score 1):

You installed PHP from the remi-php56 repository, but you have disabled that repository. Enable it and try again.

Also note that your PHP application [should not be using php-mcrypt at all](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt).

Comment: It is enabled (I believe) since I already have php5.6 (checked with phpinfo();) but no mcrypt. Ok I won't use it but what if this conflict cause more errors in the future, like updates e.t.c?

Comment: You still need to enable the repo. You can't get packages from a disabled repo.